# Batch file to open URL with disabled address bar

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file which will open a url in new window of chrome.
What I want is to open that window with address bar disabled.
I searched a lot all over the internet but couldn't find any solution.
Please let me know if anyone has any idea how to do it.
This is the code I have found so far.

```
start chrome --new-window "url"
```

Comment: A simple Google Search of: **chrome disable address bar**, would have given you the answer you were searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option I believe you are looking for is the --app=http://address.com flag.

More flags are here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ depending on what level you want removed from the window.